# Ionic Music Controls does not work | Ionic 3 + Ionic Native Media + Ionic Native Music Controls

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, media

I'm using Ionic 3 + Ionic Native Media + Ionic Native Music Controls but music controls doesn't works. Clicking Play / Pause on Music Controls nothing happen. Media streaming works well.

I've installed all cordova plugins required of course.

I've switched ON the 'Audio' option in Capabilities -> 'Background Modes' using XCODE 9.

I'm testing it on iOS (10.3 / 11) simulator and device, and on Android tablet device.

Home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <!-- Bind the click event to a method -->
<button ion-button (click)="play()">
  play file!
</button>
<button ion-button (click)="pause()">
  pause file!
</button>
</ion-content>
```

Home.ts

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';
    import { MusicControls } from '@ionic-native/music-controls';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })    
    export class HomePage {
          file: MediaObject;
          constructor(private musicControls: MusicControls, private media: Media, public navCtrl: NavController) {
          }
          play(){
            this.file = this.media.create('https://archive.org/download/db2007-05-20.rm.flac16/db2007-05-20d1t01.mp3');
            this.file.play();

            this.musicControls.destroy(); // it's the same with or without the destroy 
            this.musicControls.create({
              track       : 'Test track',        // optional, default : ''
              artist      : 'test artist',                       // optional, default : ''
              cover       : '',      // optional, default : nothing
              // cover can be a local path (use fullpath 'file:///storage/emulated/...', or only 'my_image.jpg' if my_image.jpg is in the www folder of your app)
              //           or a remote url ('http://...', 'https://...', 'ftp://...')
              isPlaying   : true,                         // optional, default : true
              dismissable : true,                         // optional, default : false

              // hide previous/next/close buttons:
              hasPrev   : false,      // show previous button, optional, default: true
              hasNext   : false,      // show next button, optional, default: true
              hasClose  : true,       // show close button, optional, default: false

            // iOS only, optional
              album       : 'test album',     // optional, default: ''
              duration : 0, // optional, default: 0
              elapsed : 0, // optional, default: 0
              hasSkipForward : true,  // show skip forward button, optional, default: false
              hasSkipBackward : true, // show skip backward button, optional, default: false
              skipForwardInterval: 15, // display number for skip forward, optional, default: 0
              skipBackwardInterval: 15, // display number for skip backward, optional, default: 0

              // Android only, optional
              // text displayed in the status bar when the notification (and the ticker) are updated
              ticker    : 'Now playing test'
             });
             this.musicControls.subscribe().subscribe(action => {
                 function events(action) {
                  console.log('action', action);
                   const message = JSON.parse(action).message;

                       switch(message) {
                           case 'music-controls-next':
                               // Do something
                               break;
                           case 'music-controls-previous':
                               // Do something
                               break;
                           case 'music-controls-pause':
                               // Do something
                               console.log('musc pause');
                               this.pause();
                               break;
                           case 'music-controls-play':
                               // Do something
                               console.log('music play');
                               this.play();
                               break;
                           case 'music-controls-destroy':
                               // Do something
                               break;
                          // External controls (iOS only)
                          case 'music-controls-toggle-play-pause' :
                            // Do something
                            break;
                          case 'music-controls-seek-to':
                            // Do something
                            break;
                          case 'music-controls-skip-forward':
                            // Do something
                            break;
                          case 'music-controls-skip-backward':
                            // Do something
                            break;

                            // Headset events (Android only)
                            // All media button events are listed below
                            case 'music-controls-media-button' :
                                // Do something
                                break;
                            case 'music-controls-headset-unplugged':
                                // Do something
                                break;
                            case 'music-controls-headset-plugged':
                                // Do something
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                   }

               this.musicControls.listen(); // activates the observable above
               this.musicControls.updateIsPlaying(true);

            });
        }

          pause(){
            this.file.pause();
          }
        }
```

I've  created a minimal ionic blank app from ionic starter, with Media play (works) and Music Controls (not works), it's available on github for testing :

https://github.com/fdambrosio/ionic-media-controls

```
Ionic Info: 

   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.1
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v6.11.2
    npm        : 5.4.2 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

With latest cordova-music-controls-plugin version (2.1.3) this problems are solved. You can test it using this repo: https://github.com/fdambrosio/ionic-media-controls

Comment: I’ve tested a lot of plugins versions, It’s working on iOS only using 1.4.1.
I've used this environment: 

cordova-plugin-music-controls@1.4.1
ionic-native/music-controls@4.2.1
cordova-ios@4.5.2

Play/pause is clickable and works, but hasPrev/hasNext buttons are always showed on iOS 11.

Comment: Can the media plugin take local file path as an audio file source? I tried 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/Tonight%20-%20Kings%20of%20Leon%20(Audio).mp3' as a source. But it didn't play.

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

radio.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, LoadingController, AlertController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MusicControls } from '@ionic-native/music-controls';
import { RadioPlayer } from '../../providers/radio-player/radio-player';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-radio',
  templateUrl: 'radio.html',
})
export class RadioPage {

  public playing: boolean = false;
  private loadingPopup: any;
  public icono: string = 'play';
  radio = {
    title: "UFM Radio",
    description: "UFPSOcaña",
    url: "http://ufm.ufpso.edu.co:8000/ufm.ogg",
    image: "assets/radioUFM.png"
  };

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private musicControls: MusicControls,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public myplayer: RadioPlayer,
  ) {

    if (this.myplayer.stream) {
      this.eventPlay(true);
    }
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.myplayer.createNotificationMusic();    // Crear el controlador de musica
      this.musicControls.listen();                // activates the observable above
      this.musicControls.subscribe().subscribe(action => {
        this.eventos(action)                      // Notificacion
      });
    }

  }

  reproductor() {
    (this.playing) ? this.pause() : this.play();    // De acuerdo al estado activa o no la musica
  }

  play() {
    this.loadingPopup = this.loadingCtrl.create({     // Crea el cargando
      spinner: 'dots',
      content: ''
    });
    this.loadingPopup.present();

    this.myplayer.play(this.radio.url).then(() => {
      this.eventPlay(true);                             /* Coloca el icono y el estado */
      this.loadingPopup.dismiss();                      // Quitar Cargando
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.musicControls.updateIsPlaying(true);     // Actualiza el icono de la barra de navegacion
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      this.presentAlert("Error msg= " + error + "<br>Radio url = " + this.radio.url);
      this.pause();
      this.eventPlay(false);
      this.loadingPopup.dismiss();
    });

  }

  public eventPlay(valor) {
    this.icono = (valor) ? 'pause' : 'play';
    this.playing = valor;
  }

  eventos(action) {
    const message = JSON.parse(action).message;
    switch (message) {
      case 'music-controls-pause':
        this.myplayer.pause();
        this.musicControls.updateIsPlaying(false);
        this.eventPlay(false);
        break;
      case 'music-controls-play':
        this.myplayer.play(this.radio.url).then(() => {
          this.musicControls.updateIsPlaying(true);
          this.eventPlay(true);
        }).catch(error => {
          this.presentAlert("Error msg= " + error + "<br>Radio url = " + this.radio.url);
          this.pause();
          this.eventPlay(false);
        });
        break;
      case 'music-controls-destroy':
        this.myplayer.pause();
        // Do something
        break;
      case 'music-controls-toggle-play-pause':
        // Do something
        break;
      case 'music-controls-seek-to':
        // Do something
        break;
      case 'music-controls-media-button':
        // Do something
        break;
      case 'music-controls-headset-unplugged':
        // Do something
        break;
      case 'music-controls-headset-plugged':
        // Do something
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  pause() {
    this.eventPlay(false);
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.musicControls.updateIsPlaying(false);
    }
    this.myplayer.pause();
  }

  presentAlert(title) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }


}
```

providers/radio-player.ts

```
import { MusicControls } from '@ionic-native/music-controls';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RadioPlayer {

    public stream: any;
    promise: any;
    radio = {
        title: "UFM Radio",
        description: "UFPSOcaña",
        url: "http://ufm.ufpso.edu.co:8000/ufm.ogg",
        image: "assets/radioUFM.png"
    };

    constructor(private musicControls: MusicControls) { };

    createNotificationMusic() {
        return this.musicControls.create({
            track: this.radio.description,
            artist: this.radio.title,
            cover: this.radio.image,
            isPlaying: false,
            dismissable: false,
            hasPrev: false,
            hasNext: false,
            hasSkipForward: false,
            hasSkipBackward: false,
            skipForwardInterval: 0,
            skipBackwardInterval: 0,
            hasClose: true,
            album: '',
            duration: 0,
            elapsed: 0,
            ticker: 'Ahora estas escuchando la' + this.radio.title
        });
    }

    play(url) {
        if (this.stream == null) {
            this.stream = new Audio(url);
            this.stream.play();
            this.stream.volume = 1;
        }

        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.stream.addEventListener('playing', () => {
                resolve(true);
            });
            this.stream.addEventListener('error', () => {
                reject(false);
            });
        });
        return this.promise;
    };

    pause() {
        this.stream.pause();
        this.stream = null;
    };




}
```

Comment: Thanks Julio, what's the plugin version that are you using? The buttons are clickable using an iOS11 device?

Comment: I am using version 2.0.0, I have not yet tested on IOS, greetings!

Comment: now this problem is  fixed with 2.1.3 cordova-music-controls-plugin version.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Jus remove the `functions(action) {` line and it's closing `}` and it will work.